# How to scroll down of specific div to locate an element and make it clickable via selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]I need to click on a button 'NEW'. The element button is visible on DOM but it's not clickable because it's overlapped and i need to scroll down left side of the page to make it clickable. I was trying inject some javascript but it didn't help in my case:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
js.executeScript("scroll(" + driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@class = 'save-new'])).getLocation().getX() + "," + driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@class = 'save-new'])).getLocation().getY() + ")");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
targetElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath"));
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
// This:
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", targetElement);
targetElement.click();
// Or maybe even just:
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", targetElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

As i feel @damian should worked but you can also tried my code I used it so mny times

Use this code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Value"));

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“arguments[0].scrollIntoView();”, element);

element.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:--

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);

  //Scroll your page to down using below code 
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“window.scroll(100,2000)”);

// click on button 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@class ='save-new'])).click()
```

Hope this help you :)